# problems with games using wine version 1.5 on ubuntu version 12.04

Tags: wine

My problem is that the screen only occupies the corner of the screen. The mouse also seems to be glitchy. I use a wide screen laptop and messing with configure wine helps a tiny bit.

the game I am trying to play is called Age of Empires 2.

Comment: Try wine 1.7 or the latest development version(whichever it may be)

Comment: your method doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Wine is, even if a game perfectly in one version of wine it may not work well in another version and sometimes it will not work at another version. So selecting the correct version for game is important.  The [wine app database](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=99) will help you to select the correct version. Also see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281160/running-age-of-empires-2-in-linux) question on AU.