# Can I play Age of Empires 2 on Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04

The only reason I still use W indows is to play this game. I tried before and couldnt get it to work on Ubuntu and I wonder if it is possible now.

Comment: Here are the full results at the WineHQ: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=99 (anything below gold is arguably a waste of time.

Comment: If all else fails, there's also [0 A.D.](https://play0ad.com/), which is somewhat similar to AoE 2 and which can be installed with `sudo apt-get install 0ad`. Bear in mind that it requires a sizeable download when installing or updating it to a new version, so be careful if you have a data cap.

Comment: I'd rather not close those as dupes, especially since it is distributed by Steam which has increasingly more Linux native games: http://store.steampowered.com/app/221380/Age_of_Empires_II_HD/

Comment: does steam not work?

Comment: I'm not running 14.04 but you could try my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1013937/512236)

Answer (score 8):

I personally vote for **Playonlinux**. Playonlinux is a third party wine wrapper and has the necessary script for AOE2.

You can install Playonlinux by

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

then in Playonlinux install menu choose Age of Empires 2 and prepare your disk with AOE2, then follow the install steps on the screen.

Comment: does steam not work?